# mod_jk produces incorrect redirect query string with Lucee and Apache

Tags: apache, coldfusion, lucee

I am getting too many redirects after implementing a solution to THIS problem
"mod_jk to shows/append index.cfm?&_modcfmlredirected on page load"

I am trying to run Lucee CF with Apache 2.4 on a windows EC2 instance.

Install of both Apache 2.4 and Lucee went fine - both services come up fine and restart fine... Apache conf is pointed to a webroot - and test page comes up fine.

I have followed instructions on implementing mod_jk - but when I tested a simple index.cfm - I got this:

```
index.cfm?&_modcfmlredirected
```

I found multiple answers - that all recommended updating your 'mod_cfml-valve_v1.1.09.jar' to 'mod_cfml-valve_v1.1.10.jar'.

So I did...

And now I get this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.cfm?&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__&__

This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

reverting to the 1.1.09 file brings back the ?&_modcfmlredirected as expected.

The code of index.cfm is simply

```
CF Index : 
<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>
```

This is not a 'code' issue....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**** ADDITIONAL INFORMATION ****
this redirect happens when viewing file from localhost (127.0.0.1)
however, when I view the page from outside the server - I get a 403 - Forbidden error.

don't know id this helps - I hope so.

Comment: Can you do a redirect with <cflocation> instead?

Comment: to what end...?
the webserver is redirecting automatically - not the code...